# UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate landscape Transition

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uikit

What is the best practice to create landscaped transition between two UIViewControllers? The containerView

```
UIView * container      = [transitionContext containerView];
```

logs the frame : `{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}` which is vertical and any added subview is added vertically. Should I rotate added subviews or add subviews to on of the controllers view and not the container view directly?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I dont recall having found a solution to this one.